# PagerView with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a **ListView** with books. When I click the row I am able to see book details in new **fragment**, something similar like in [Training Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html). I would like to slide books (right -> next element from the list, left <- previous element from the list).

**PROBLEM** 
How to integrate **ViewPager** with fragements? When I click element on the list FragmentTransaction is invoke.

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RecyclerViewFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final Fragment mFragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, mFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int id) {

        Log.d("Element Id ", String.valueOf(id));

        PagerViewFragment newFragment = new PagerViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PagerViewFragment.ARG_POSITION, id);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

How to inform fragment that should change the view?
Should I use this code?

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

***EDIT***

 After **ILovemyPancho** answer stack again. *java.lang.NullPointerException*:

PagerViewFragment:

```
public class PagerViewFragment extends Fragment {
    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    public PagerViewFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup viewRoot = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_fragment, container, false);
        mPager = (ViewPager) container.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);  //line 39. Error is here

        return viewRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            PagerViewFragment frag = new PagerViewFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("BookTitle", "FD");

            DummyContent dummyContent = new DummyContent(); //elements

            TextView street = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.street_article);
            street.setText(dummyContent.murals.get(position).getStreet());

            TextView artist = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.artist_article);
            artist.setText(dummyContent.murals.get(position).getArtists().get(0).getName());
            frag.setArguments(args);

            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return DummyContent.murals.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
}
```

MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RecyclerViewFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final Fragment mFragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, mFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int id) {

        Log.d("Element Id ", String.valueOf(id));

        PagerViewFragment newFragment = new PagerViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PagerViewFragment.ARG_POSITION, id);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

activity_screen_slide.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

pager_fragmet.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/blank_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.szymon.fragmentexample.BlankFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/street_article"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="hello_blank_fragment"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist_article"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/street_article"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="hello_blank_fragment"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/artist_article"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="here will be the picture"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I got an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.szymon.recyclerview.PagerViewFragment.onCreateView(PagerViewFragment.java:39)
>               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: @ILovemyPoncho sure, I know this page, but how to implement it in my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So you have an Activity dislaying a ListFragment (`RecyclerViewFragment`). When you click a list item, ListFragment is replaced by `PagerViewFragment` showing the details of the book.

Try this. Create a fragment containing the ViewPager. This fragment is going to replace your ListFragment when an item is clicked. Lets call it  `BookDetailsContainer`, and is going to receive the list item id:

```
 BookDetailsContainer newFragment = BookDetailsContainer.newInstance(id);
```

Inside this fragment you set the viewpager:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

`getChildFragmentManager()` is needed by the ViewPager to handle the nested fragments (the PagerViewFragment inside the BookDetailsContainer). And since you passed the list position id to the `BookDetailsContainer`, you can set the position:

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(positionId);
```

In your `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter`, you are going to create a `PagerViewFragment` instance,
get the information to display from your data source (array, cursor...) based on the
position, pass that data to the fragment using a Bundle, and return the fragment:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    PagerViewFragment frag = new PagerViewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    //get data from your data source based on the "position"

    args.putString("BookTitle", ...);
    args.putString("BookAuthor", ...);
    ...

    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
```

And that's basically how you can do it.

Comment: I'm closer to find solution, but your answer didn't solve my problem yet. I hope you will be able to solve it now.

Comment: It seems you are not inflating `activity_screen_slide.xml`, when you try to find the ViewPager, it returns null and you can't set the adapter. Don't set the TextViews inside getItem(), it should be done in onCreateView(). The fragment containing the viewpager shouldn't be the same fragment returned from getItem().

You need a fragment to inflate `activity_screen_slide.xml` there you are going to find the ViewPager and set the Adapter. And another different fragment to inflate `pager_fragment.xml` there you are going to find and set the TextViews, this one will be returned from getItem().

Comment: @ILovemyPancho Do you have any example code? Tutorial? It seems to be much harder. The adapter should be in PagerViewFragment. In this clas I should inflant 'BookDetailsContainer' as written above. In 'BookDetailsContainer' I should inflate mPager and mAdapter?

Comment: There you are mate https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested